# Getting a Soft Keyboard for a EditTextPreference

Tags: android, android-edittext, preference

I have a shared preference that is being accesed via an EditTextPreference.  I am in the process of porting this application to a device that does not have a hardware keyboard for text entry.

When the time comes to modify the EditTextPreference, there is no soft keyboard that becomes available, and I am at a loss as to how to invoke the soft keyboard for text input to edit this preference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`EditTextPreference` supports most of the same XML properties as does the `EditText` widget. So, you can use stuff like `android:inputType`, `android:imeOptions`, and kin to tailor the soft keyboard.

However, AFAIK, the soft keyboard is automatic for `EditTextPreferences` -- it should work without configuration.